# /v1/payments/payment/ always returns an empty array

Tags: jquery, ajax, paypal

created a test-app and a test-account.
the test-account has numerous transactions, firstCall is successful, it returns the access_token me, I use to call "**/v1/payments/payment/**", this, I always returns an empty array ...

```js
/* -- */
function pp() {

    this.r = false;
    this.R = function(r) {
        this.r = $("body").data("ppfirstcall");
    };
    this.firstCall = function() {
        $.ajax({
            headers : {
                "Accept" : "application/json",
                "Accept-Language" : "en_US",
                "Authorization" : "Basic " + btoa("[Client ID]:[Secret]")
            },
            url : "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token",
            type : "POST",
            data : "grant_type=client_credentials",
            complete : function(result) {

                $("body").data("ppfirstcall", result.responseJSON);

                //ppInvoice(result.responseJSON.access_token);
                var ppAccTok =  result.responseJSON.access_token;
                var tokType = result.responseJSON.token_type;

                $.ajax({
                    headers : {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                        "Authorization":"Bearer "+ppAccTok
                    },

                    //url : "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/invoicing/search",
                    url : "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/",
                    type : "get",
                    processData: false,
                    //data : JSON.stringify(data),
                    complete: function(ppR)
                    {
                        console.log(tokType,ppAccTok,ppR);
                    }
                }  );

                console.log( "complete:",result.responseJSON.access_token, result.responseJSON );
            },
        });
    };
};

function runPP()
{
    pp = new pp();
    pp.firstCall();
}
/*  ----  */
```

Comment: that **ppR.responseTex**t always returns `"{" count ": 0}"`